# How to change symbol in string using c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

My C# application is able store the data into a SQL Server database. Currently I have to problem when user insert symbol ' in their string/sentences:

Example: I want to 'test' your system

So, when inserting into db the ' symbol will return an error while inserting by using sql query.

My query example :

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (POST_BODY) 
VALUES ('i want to 'test' your system')
```

and then my plan here is to change that check the string if contains that ' symbol it will change to " symbol.

I have try using this code, but cannot:

```
 void ChangeSymbol(String str)
 {
        Console.WriteLine("\"{0}\"", str);
        Console.WriteLine("\"{0}\"", str.Replace(''', '"'));
 }
```

Please anybody help to give some idea to face this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide some more code. Especially the one you're using for data insertion?

Comment: Use a **parametrized query** - it's both safe against SQL injection, and also doesn't have any issues with adding single quotes and things like that. It's the **preferred way** to go anyways!

Comment: maybe - `command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param", "i want to 'test' your system"); `

Comment: @Orlig Anbiz Try this :  `Console.WriteLine("\"{0}\"", str.Replace("'", "\""));`

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem inserting a single quote into a database using SQL code.  If you want to insert a text literal then you simply escape the single quote with another single quote, e.g.

`INSERT INTO MyTable (GivenName, FamilyName) VALUES ('James', 'O''Connell')`

If you're inserting a separate value into a SQL statement then you should be using parameters no matter the data type, so an issue with single quotes never arises, e.g.

```
mySqlCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO MyTable (GivenName, FamilyName) VALUES (@GivenName, @FamilyName)";
mySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GivenName", givenName);
mySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FamilyName", familyName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use parameter binding. I don't have a sample code to put in since we dont use MSSQL

here's a sample
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score -2):

You escape single quotes by doubling them. So try this:

```
string example = "I want to ''test'' your system";
```